# Create a full screen image under my menu

Tags: html, css

I am working on SJ Vinda template in Joomla, and what I am trying to do is set a custom html module, that contains an image, in slideshow position, and force it to take the size of the screen that every user will use. The support team gave me a code to override the slideshow css:

```css
#yt_slideshow .container{
    width: 100%;
}
#slideshow .module div.modcontent{
    padding: 0;
}
```

However this one will turn the module position to full width. I need it to resize the image, and cut part of it, in order to appear to the whole screen. Example of what I am trying to do: http://www.orangedigital.com.au/

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Tried google? Here's a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to make a full screen slideshow, you can use any full-screen slider, like Superslides. If you are using the image as `background-image`, then setting `background-size:cover` will solve your problem. However the example site link you gave, something different is going on there. They have used an image with `position:fixed` property, and resized it using javascript. If you want somthing like that, then you need to do it by javascript.

Comment: The last one that you mention is what I would like to do. However I don't have enough knownledge of javascrip and I was hopping that a combination of css and php could work!

Comment: Not sure if that's possible with PHP... You need to do it at client's side... Better to use javascript...